# Stay on top app launched with CreateProcessA()

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I need to launch a Google Chrome window in app mode. And I need this window to stay on top.

I open the browser with this code:

```
string command = Browser_Path + " --new-window --window-size=400,600 --window-position=30,30 --app=https://192.168.1.118/modules/clientSupervisor/index.php?" + params;

char                    cmdline[512];
strcpy(cmdline, command.c_str());
PROCESS_INFORMATION     pi;
STARTUPINFOA            si;

BOOL                    bOk;
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
bOk = CreateProcessA(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si,&pi);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

I need the new window to stay on top, although the user clicks on other apps.

Do you know any trick to achieve it? Maybe, with any param on `STARTUPINFOA` structure?

Comment: The fact that any given window is forced to the top of the Z-order doesn't prevent any other window from gaining foreground activation and input focus. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, the approach you seem to have in mind is unlikely part of the solution.

Comment: [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) doesn't support the topmost function. Generally, `WS_EX_TOPMOST` or [Setting UIAccess in the Application Manifest File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-securityoverview#setting-uiaccess-in-the-application-manifest-file) are used.

Answer (score 3):

The "always on top" attribute belongs to a window, not to the application in general.

So the general idea is to wait for the application to finish launching, then find its main window, then use `SetWindowPos` to make it a topmost window.

But, at least as far as I know, there's no straightforward way to find the main window created by particular process, so you need to enumerate the top-level windows, then call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` on each to get the process ID associated with each window, and look for one with a process ID that matches the one you got from `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your comment is so usefull. I got it to work by searching by window title, and the window stays above the other ones. I'll try to achive searching by process Id or thread Id, the problem is that Google Chrome creates so many differents PID, and the main one created (which I launch in my code) doesn't match with the one that "contains the visible window".

Comment: @Ricardo: Yeah, that would get difficult for Chrome.